# Reading an audio file from listview item

Tags: java, android

How can i get to read the audio of a song that i can see in a listview?

```
    listAllSongs.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mediaPlayer.selectTrack(position);
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get your audio file from the list using `position` as index.

```
listAllSongs.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mediaPlayer.selectTrack(audioList.get(position).getSong()); //use appropriate method to get your audio file
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
    });
```